# cakephp send batch email with dynamic content

Tags: email, cakephp, postmark

I had a strange problem with email sending through cakephp and postmark.

I have installed [postmark-cakephp library](https://github.com/maurymmarques/postmark-cakephp) in my cakephp application. I'm able to send email to single user and able to send email to multiple users with same email content (message) but here my requirement is I need to send email to multiple users with some dynamic email content. (contains user id)

I'm able to do this in a for loop but I want to send batch emails with dynamic content with a single call.

Here is my code

```
foreach($send as $client) {
   //if client contains emails, send email
   if(!empty($client['Email'])) {
      //loop through emails
      foreach($client['Email'] as $to) {
         $client['message'] .= 'To be removed visit http://something.com/remove/'.$to."\n";
        $client['message'] .= $message_footer;
        $email_to = new CakeEmail();
        $email_to->config('postmark');
        $email_to->from('admin@something.com');
        $email_to->to($to);
        $email_to->subject($subject);
        $email_to->send($client['message']);
    }
 }
```

}

Please help me out.

Comment: Ok I understand but what have you done so far? where is the code?

Comment: I have updated the query with my sample code. Please check it.

Comment: I don't know how you expect to be able to send multiple emails with _different_ content without some sort of loop somewhere. The solution seems obvious put "I'm able to do this in a for loop" in a method and call it to achieve " I want to send batch emails with dynamic content with a single call."

Comment: you can create email templates (different contents)  and pass variables to email.

Answer (score 0):

Postmark has a "[batch](http://developer.postmarkapp.com/developer-api-email.html#batch-emails)" API feature but it doesn't look like it's supported in the CakePHP lib you're using. There is an [official Postmark library](http://developer.postmarkapp.com/developer-official-libs.html#php) which *should* work ok with Cake but you may have to do a little bit of integration. This library supports the batch API so you can construct all the dynamic messages for individual users and send them in one API call.